# Пул потоков в связке с асинхронными задачами

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-threads

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я начал изучать многопоточность и столкнулся с проблемой что ExecutorService не работает в связке с ассинхронными задачами.

Схематично нарисовал свой проект.

> Когда нажимаешь на кнопку запускатся `startService` в Нем срабатывает
>   `onStartCommand` после идут 3 ассихнронных интернет запроса. Я сделал
>   их путем sincroinzed синхронными.
>
> После запуска 1 функции запускается 2, затем 3, за ним 4 и в
>   конце запускается отдельный поток.

---

Используя ExecutorService я попытался нажать несколько раз на кнопку результат все перемещалось.

Поэтому я ищу выход из этой ситуации.

> Что я ожидаю:

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку 1 раз или 10 не важно. То создается пул потоков в потоке запускается 1 блок.

Но остальные потоки не должны работать пока не закончится `текущий поток` который выполнит весь цикл нарисованный красным квадратом.

Как только текущий поток закончит работу, то должна быть проверка нет ли в очереди других потоков, если есть то по новой следующий поток должен выполнит тоже самое с 1 блока по 5 блока и т.д.

ExecutorService видимо не подойдет для этого так как он работает только с Thread.
А как видимо на схеме у меня все в перемещку.

### Код

```
public class ServiceOfflineLoader extends Service {

    private ModelSubCategoriesItems.CoursesBean coursesBean;
    private CourseDetailItem courseDetailItem;
    private LessonCourseAccess lessonCourseAccess;
    private List<String> listLessonFile=new ArrayList<>();
    private List<VideoItem> listVideoItem=new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Response> listVideoSubtitle=new ArrayList<>();
    private String strCourseID="";
    private int indexLessonRequest=0;
    private Realm realm;
    private String strUrlVideo="";
    private String strUrlSubtitle="";
    private String strFileVideoName="";
    private String strFileSubtitle="";
    private OfflineDataRealm offlineDataRealm;
    private Gson gson;
    private String strJson="";
    private SharedPrefHelper sharedPrefHelper;

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public ServiceOfflineLoader() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sharedPrefHelper=new SharedPrefHelper(this);
        gson=new Gson();
        executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("ServiceOfflineLoader=onStartCommand", "START SERVICE" + "");
        if (intent!=null){
            Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
            coursesBean= (ModelSubCategoriesItems.CoursesBean) bundle.getSerializable(GlobalConstants.INTENT_COURSE_BEAN);
            RequestsRB.requestCourseItemDetail(this, coursesBean.id);
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }

    class LoaderThread extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Log.e("LoaderThread=run", "Run1" + "");
            realm= Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            try{
                offlineDataRealm= new OfflineDataRealm();

                for (int i = 0; i < listLessonFile.size(); i++) {
                    Response response=listVideoItem.get(i).getResponse();
                    strUrlVideo=response.getLink().get(0).getFile();
                    strFileVideoName=strUrlVideo;
                    strFileVideoName=strFileVideoName.substring(strFileVideoName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    File fileVideo= new File(getFilesDir() + "/"+strFileVideoName);
                    Utils.donwloadUrlToSaveFile(strUrlVideo,fileVideo);

                    for (int j = 0; j < response.getCaptions().size(); j++) {
                        Caption caption=response.getCaptions().get(j);
                        strUrlSubtitle=caption.getFile();
                        strFileSubtitle=strUrlSubtitle;
                        strFileSubtitle=strFileSubtitle.substring(strFileSubtitle.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        File fileSubtitle= new File(getFilesDir() + "/"+strFileSubtitle);
                        Utils.donwloadUrlToSaveFile(strUrlSubtitle,fileSubtitle);
                    }

                    RealmString realmStringVideoItem=new RealmString();
                    strJson=gson.toJson( listVideoItem.get(i) );
                    realmStringVideoItem.setValue(strJson);
                    offlineDataRealm.strJsonVideoItem.add(realmStringVideoItem);

                    RealmString realmStringVideoSubtitle=new RealmString();
                    strJson=gson.toJson( listVideoItem.get(i).getResponse() );
                    realmStringVideoSubtitle.setValue(strJson);
                    offlineDataRealm.strJsonVideoSubtitle.add( realmStringVideoSubtitle );

                }

                strJson=gson.toJson(coursesBean);
                offlineDataRealm.strJsonModelSubCategoriesItems=strJson;

                strJson=gson.toJson(lessonCourseAccess);
                offlineDataRealm.strJsonResponseBodyAccess =strJson;

                strJson=gson.toJson(courseDetailItem);
                offlineDataRealm.strJsonCourseDetailItem=strJson;

                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealm(offlineDataRealm);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                realm.close();
            }
            Log.e("LoaderThread=run", "Close Run" + "");
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        switch (event.message) {
            case RESPONSE_COURSE_DETAIL:
                Log.e("ServiceOfflineLoader=onMessageEvent", "RESPONSE!!!!!!!!" + "");
                courseDetailItem= (CourseDetailItem) event.link;
                RequestsRB.getAccessCourse(this, coursesBean.id, sharedPrefHelper.getUserLanguage(), GlobalConstants.TOKEN);
                break;
            case RESPONSE_GET_COURSE_ACCESS:
                ResponseBody responseBody=(ResponseBody) event.link;
                try {
                    lessonCourseAccess=new Gson().fromJson(responseBody.string(),LessonCourseAccess.class);
                } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                filterCourseAccess();
                strCourseID=courseDetailItem.getResponse().getCourseID();

                listLessonFile.clear();
                listVideoItem.clear();
                listVideoSubtitle.clear();
                indexLessonRequest=0;

                for (Map.Entry<String,ChaptersBean> entry: lessonCourseAccess.response.chapters.entrySet()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().lessons.size(); i++) {
                        listLessonFile.add( entry.getValue().lessons.get(i).lessonId );
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < listLessonFile.size(); i++) {
                    RequestsRB.requestVideo(this, strCourseID, listLessonFile.get(i),sharedPrefHelper.getUserLanguage());
                }
                break;
            case RESPONSE_VIDEO_ITEM:
                VideoItem videoItem= (VideoItem) event.link;
                listVideoItem.add(videoItem);
                listVideoSubtitle.add( videoItem.getResponse() );
                indexLessonRequest++;

                if (indexLessonRequest==listLessonFile.size()){
                    LoaderThread loaderThread =new LoaderThread();
                    executorService.execute(loaderThread);
                    indexLessonRequest=0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void filterCourseAccess() {
        boolean isCourseAccess = lessonCourseAccess.response.isAccess;

        if (!isCourseAccess){
            Map.Entry<String,ChaptersBean> firstChapterBean=lessonCourseAccess.response.chapters.entrySet().iterator().next();
            lessonCourseAccess.response.chapters.clear();

            ChaptersBean chaptersBean=firstChapterBean.getValue();
            List<ChaptersBean.LessonsBean> lessonsBeans=new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < chaptersBean.lessons.size(); i++) {
                if (i==3){
                    break;
                }
                lessonsBeans.add( chaptersBean.lessons.get(i) );
            }

            chaptersBean.lessons.clear();
            chaptersBean.lessons.addAll( lessonsBeans );

            lessonCourseAccess.response.chapters.put(firstChapterBean.getKey(),chaptersBean);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код приложите .

Comment: Асинхронные задачи создают собственные потоки, которые не управляются экзекутором. Для того чтобы всё это синхронизировать нужно писать своё подобие eventthread'а или сделать все подзадачи синхронными

Comment: @woesss, Спасибо. Пришлось переписат и сдеклат синхронными теперь все работает. А что разве в больних проектах нету активити которые используют синхронные и ассинхронные задачи?